# Xamarin get data from Web API

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm trying do a simple app in Xamarin where I can see the current weather in my city. But I cant seem to get it right.. I've got the api from openweathermap.org, where in the url I'm searching for my city's coordinates.
To get the classes for my "OpenWeather" class, I used json2csharp, to generate my class.

I want to display the city name, weatherdescription and the coordinates.

I'll post the code I got so far:

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        GetWeather();

    }

    public async void GetWeather()
    {

        try
        {
            string URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=58.34&lon=11.94&appid=((((((MY API KEY))))))))))))";

            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri(URL));

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var weatherList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(content);

                //Databind the list
                lstWeather.ItemsSource = weatherList;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //ToDo Give errormessage to user and possibly log error
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml:

```
<ProgressBar IsEnabled="True"></ProgressBar>
<ListView x:Name="lstWeather">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">-->
                        <Label  Text="{Binding name}" />
                        <Label  Text="{Binding desciption}" Margin="20,0,0,0"/>
                        <Label  Text="{Binding lon}" Margin="20,0,0,0"/>
                        <Label  Text="{Binding lat}" Margin="20,0,0,0"/>
                   </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>


namespace TestApp
```

{
    public class Coord
    {
        public double lon { get; set; }
        public double lat { get; set; }
    }

```
public class Weather
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string main { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string icon { get; set; }
}

public class Main
{
    public double temp { get; set; }
    public int pressure { get; set; }
    public int humidity { get; set; }
    public double temp_min { get; set; }
    public double temp_max { get; set; }
}

public class Wind
{
    public double speed { get; set; }
    public int deg { get; set; }
}

public class Clouds
{
    public int all { get; set; }
}

public class Sys
{
    public int type { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public double message { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public int sunrise { get; set; }
    public int sunset { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Coord coord { get; set; }
    public List<Weather> weather { get; set; }
    public string @base { get; set; }
    public Main main { get; set; }
    public int visibility { get; set; }
    public Wind wind { get; set; }
    public Clouds clouds { get; set; }
    public int dt { get; set; }
    public Sys sys { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int cod { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: "can't seem to get it right" is not a helpful description of your problem.  What specifically are you having trouble with?  Are you getting an error or exception?

Comment: @Jason Oh sorry! My exception for the moment is in my MainPage.xaml.cs file where the errormessage is: "Cannot Implicity convert type 'TestApp.RootObject' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I'm not even sure if my syntax is right to print out what I want, when that problem is fixed..

Answer (score 1):

the problem is here:

```
lstWeather.ItemsSource = weatherList;
```

`weatherList` is an `RootObject`, but a `ListView` requires an `IEnumerable` for it's datasource

You probably want to do this:

```
lstWeather.ItemsSource = weatherList.weather;
```

Comment: That helped me get rid of my error. Now I can start the app, but its blank. If I hover with my mouse I can see that there's a listitem there. When I put a breakpoint at lstWeather.ItemsSource = weatherList.weather; I can see the object I want to see. 

Maybe my databinding in the xaml is wrong?

Comment: each individual item in your list is a Weather object, so your bindings need to be properties of Weather

Comment: Well, I get this in the output window though.. https://imgur.com/a/n4qZF

How will the databinding be then?
<Label  Text="{Binding weather.name}" /> ?

Comment: the weather class doesn't have a name property

Comment: but I thought that with this 
"var weatherList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(content);"

I created a list of Rootobject which contains "name" ?

Comment: no, the weather api returns a single Root object, which contains a list of Weather objects.

Comment: What is your list supposed to display?  Is it a list of multiple locations and their forecasts?  Or is it a list of a single location with multiple forecasts over time?

Comment: I want to display the name of the city (for which I have longitude and latitude for in my api link: http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=58.34&lon=11.94) 
I also want to display the description of the weather (example: "rainy") and the coordinates. Maybe temp also, but I see that the json text return in calvin so it might be a bit difficult to convert to celsius for now. But; name, description and coordinates is the things I want!

Comment: but if every item in the list is the same City and coordinates, what is the point of repeating them in every cell?  That is poor UI design

Comment: yes that might be hehe.. But how will I solve my problem? I appreciate your help

Comment: this is turning into a question about data binding, which is not really what you originally asked.  I'd suggest asking another question (search first) abound binding to a parent reference.  Or see here for a hint: https://martynnw.wordpress.com/2017/02/12/xamarin-forms-binding-list-item-commands-to-the-parent-viewmodel/

Comment: sorry but that didn’t help :/ Do you know how to solve this one?

Answer (score 0):

```
var weatherList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(content);
```

I think this line needs to be as follows:

```
var weatherList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(content);
```